Filter contact lookups on Object by Account-Contact relation
I've been looking into using Account-Contact relations. I kind of assumed I would be able to filter lookups to contacts on Objects that are associated with an account by Account-Contact relations. For example, if I have a "Customer" field on an Object that is associated with an account, I want to make sure you can only see contacts with the "Customer" relationship to the Account this particular record is associated with. Is there any way to achieve this that I've been missing?

Unfortunately you're not going to be able to do this via a Lookup Filter. We can only use fields on either of the records, or on a directly related record. Because the Account-Contact Relation is a junction between the Account and Contact, it isn't available for the filter. You can either look at using a Flow/LWC as a Quick Action to provide a better input experience, or use a Record Triggered Flow/Trigger to validate the data entered if it is for a data quality issue.
